# A function which is not identically zero has positive integral for some ball.

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}^d$, and $f$ is not identically zero.

The hint in my book is telling me that there exists some ball such that $\int_{B} |f| > 0$

Suppose $f= \chi_{\mathbb{Q}}$, the indicator function on the rationals. This function is not identically zero and I'm fairly certain the integral would always be zero.

How is my reasoning wrong?

Comment: Your example is not (Riemann-)integrable, so does not contradict the problem.

Comment: But it is Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: @ggfgfg What book are you using ?

Comment: Real Analysis III, Stein + Shakarchi

Comment: As (almost) everywhere (pun intended) where measurable/integrable functions are concerned, the property "identically zero" has to be interpreted in the "almost everywhere" sense.

Comment: And a function not being zero almost everywhere is equivalent to there existing a set of nonzero measure on which f is bounded away from zero.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\int_{B}|f|=0$, then $f=0$ almost everywhere on $B$. Otherwise if there exists $E\subset B$ such that $|E|>0$ and $f\neq0$ on $E$, then $\int_{B}|f|>\int_{E}|f|>0$.

Now if $\int_{B}|f|=0$ for all open balls in $\mathbb{R^{d}}$, then $f=0$ almost everywhere on all open balls in $\mathbb{R^{d}}$. Since the open balls generate the $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R^{d}}$, $f=0$ almost everywhere on $\mathbb{R^{d}}$.

Comment: You don't need the balls to generate the $\sigma$-algebra. This is neither necessary nor sufficient for your conclusion. The relevant property is that a countable union of open balls covers $\Bbb{R}^n$.